# Access 2007 Form Event Code gets disconnected from the event

Tags: ms-access

Oops - I see now - I changed to use a Tabbed interface and I cut/pasted the controls to different tabs.

I think this broke the event link, but it's easy enough to regain.

---------------------- Original -----------------

In course of building a Form with code behind the events, the code on most of my control events got disconnected -- 
By that I mean, 
First, the code does not fire and when looking at the properties panel, the "After Update" event shows a blank, but if I click the "..." and choose "Code Builder" it goes right to the code and after this, the code triggers okay.

Is there any way to re-connect the code to the event without going through each control and clicking the "..."  ??

Thank you, 
Lee Shelton

Comment: This http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/event-procedure-code-behind-form-t3483956.html suggests that a cut and paste of the code may work. You may wish to look at decompile first.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of setting the event handler, firstly as you say, in the designer you can click the builder and choose code builder. Secondly you can just put a `[` in the property and it will auto complete to `[Event Procedure]`.

You can also do it in code i.e.

```
Forms![Form1].Controls!Combo0.AfterUpdate = "[Event Procedure]"
```

The last two methods don't create the code outline like the first does, so you will need to create that, or just click the builder to create it.

If you have different controls on separate tabs then you may be able to re-use an event handler. To do this instead of entering `[Event Procedure]` against the event put `=MyAfterUpdate("Bob")` you need to declare this as a function, but you can pass whatever parameters you like.

```
Function MyAfterUpdate(PersonName As String)
    MsgBox "Hi " & PersonName
End Function
```